# Google Colab can't to hosted notebook disabled button

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Hi I'm having some trouble here ..

I've ran some google cloud machine with a nice GPU, jupyter notebook is up, the link works, except I can't click the connect button under the colab interface once I've entered the url ..

It seems like it only accepts links begining with localhost ..

I even tried removing the disabled attribute, but still, colab won't let me connect to an operational notebook ..

Does anyone have a clue on how to fix it ?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can connect colab to a Google Compute Engine backend, but you must do it via a localhost ssh tunnel. There are instructions at https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html